# python3 regular expression multiline

Tags: regex, python-3.x, multiline

I have read the tutorial on this and a fair amount of post and I am having trouble python3 regex matching in multi line mode. Consider the simple test:

```
text = "abcdef\nghijkl"
exp1 = "^.*(def)"
exp2 = "^.*(jkl)"
print(text)
import re
re.compile(exp1, re.MULTILINE).match(text) is not None
re.compile(exp2, re.MULTILINE).match(text) is not None
```

This results in:

```
abcdef
ghijkl
True
False
```

This is the most basic example I could find, and all the other online regex matching ones of tried show that both should match with multi line but this doesn't. What am I missing? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should use `re.S`, not `re.M`, flag.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why would I need both? if I have the re.S then that will just include the new line as a character for the '.'. correct?

Comment: `.match`  requires the match to be at the start of the string regasrdless of the `re.M` flag. The `^` with `re.match` makes no sense. Or use `re.search`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thankyou! yes the way regex standard defines it it is actually .search!